# Filtering Google Maps with jQuery

Tags: jquery, maps

Is there a way to filter Google Maps location variables with jQuery?

Ex:

Car

Boat

Clicking on the link with ID car, filters all strings with ID car. 
Clicking by the ID car hides all strings with ID boat on the Maps and show only strings with ID car in the Maps.

Is it possible?

```
function initialize() {

    var locations = [


  ['<strong>Firm 1</strong><br />1111 Country<br />Street<br /><br />', 47.6801806,8.7499505, 1, id car here?? ],

  ['<strong>Firm 2</strong><br />2222 Country<br />Street<br /><br />', 47.6801806,8.7499505, 2, id boat here?? ],



];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.603786, 9.055737),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });






    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
       icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('/assets/templates/style/images/iconKarte.png')
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

 }

</script>




 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px;height:500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform following [as shown in this JsFiddle with a lot of redundant code](http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/XLHDg/show/)

1. Once the map object is there. populate it with all of your markers
2. When Someone clicks on filter (for example in my fiddle click on cars or people) and it will clear the map and redraw markers from the unordered list for people only. The function will not change where you have zoomed or pan but you can do that easily.
3. There is no step 3. Maybe you want them to go back to original all objects on map so put a function for showing all markers.

The actual piece of code that filters is:

```
{clear:{}},
{ action: 'addMarkers',
marker:{
values:ulmarkerspeople,
options:{
    draggable: false,
    icon:'http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-ffc11f/shapecolor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-white/symbolshadowstyle-dark/gradient-no/male-2.png'
}}
```

I am using gmap3 to clear with an empty object as it allows to clear tags or ids as well. if you are using google map v3 API then use `{action:'clear'}` to clear the map before you redraw markers.

Comment: Mark it as an answer when you can